# FFT and FIFO connection

Tags: verilog, fft, xilinx

I would like to ask you something if there's anyone who knows FPGA and xilinx FFT core. I'm trying to implement this core on my FPGA board and I want to connect it to FIFO memory to create a good synchronization for the core.

My question is about connecting this FIFO with FFT, can I for example connect the ports at the output of the FIFO directly to the ports of the FFT's input as shown below in the figure, or I should do some control logic between the cores.

Notice that I'm using FFT core v9.0 with Vivado design tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For synchronization problem, you should use aync FIFO instead of normal FIFO. 
If you are using data valid, you should concatenate the control signal to data signal and "sync" to different clock domain together.